# Calculate percentage in mysql from the same column

Tags: mysql

How do i calculate the percentage from the same column, between two dates?

I have column `latest`. 
**For example:** 2015-11-16 the value was 159,4 and today the value is 160,1.

And between these dates there is other values, that i´m not interested in at the moment. How to i calculate the percentage difference from that specific date, compared to "todays" date.

**EDIT**

```
SELECT curr.latest * 100 / NULLIF(prev.latest, 0) as percentage
FROM myTable AS curr, myTable AS prev 
WHERE date(prev.timestamp) = '2015-11-16' 
AND date(curr.timestamp) = CURDATE() 
AND curr.the_row_namn = 'apple'
```

Percentage of column `latest` of a specific date ex. 2015-11-16, with the `the_row_namn` of apple from the table `myTable`.

*What is the percentage difference of column `latest` for `apple` of `the day` 2015-11-16 to `today`.*

```
+--------------+--------+------------+
| the_row_namn | latest | timestamp  |
+--------------+--------+------------+
| apple        | 159,40 | 2015-11-16 |
| apple        | 164,1  | 2015-11-17 |
+--------------+--------+------------+
```

Expected output: (rounded) `percentage: 0,2864` or even better if that is possible `2,8%`

Hope this will clarify things.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the name of your table, and the name of your value column. We currently only have the name of one of the columns (`latest`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT     curr.name,
           curr.value * 100 / NULLIF(prev.value, 0) as percentage
FROM       myTable AS curr
INNER JOIN myTable AS prev
        ON curr.name = prev.name
WHERE      prev.latest = '2015-10-26'
AND        curr.latest = CURDATE()
AND        curr.name = 'apple';
```

If you leave out the last condition, you'll get a result per possible value of `name`.

The main point of this query is that you use your table twice, once to select the current record, and once to retrieve the earlier record. You should just specify the date of your choice in the first line of the `where` clause.

Once you have both records, it is straightforward to calculate a percentage from the `value` columns of these two records.

The `NULLIF` is there to protect you from `division by zero` errors. Instead you'll get a `NULL` result.

Comment: This seems like a nice approach, thanks! But, I'm having one problems.. =) I think i left out some vital information in my question. Im trying to fetch the specific row as well, with no luck. `SELECT curr.latest * 100 / NULLIF(prev.latest, 0) as percentage FROM myTable  AS curr, myTable  AS prev WHERE  date(prev.timestamp) = '2015-11-16' AND date(curr.timestamp) = CURDATE() AND curr.the_name_column = 'apple'` How do i fetch the result for name `apple` in this example?

Comment: Can you add this information in your question itself? I updated my answer to make use of a `name` column in the way you describe.

Comment: Thank you for your time! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is the general form such a query can take:

```
SELECT a.value / b.value AS abPerc
FROM the_table AS a 
INNER JOIN the_table AS b ON [pairing criteria]
;
```